# Last ID in MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching a query to find the last ID in a table.

I already have tried these two query's

```
$querycustomerid="SELECT IDCustomer FROM tblCustomer ORDER BY IDCustomer DESC LIMIT 1";
$newid = mysql_query($querycustomertid) or die ("Error in : $querycustomerid. ".mysql_error()) + 1;

$querycustomerid="SELECT MAX(IDCustomer) FROM tblCustomer";
$newid = mysql_query($querycustomerid) or die ("Error in : $querycustomerid. ".mysql_error()) + 1;
```

but when i echo $newid in php i get back Resource id #3

Comment: You need to fetch results from your query result (mysql_fetch_assoc). The query result alone is a resource object and not a dataset.

Comment: To clarify: Are you looking for the next available `ID` in an auto-incremented column? Or just looking for the largest existing value of `ID`?

Comment: I think there are several things wrong here.  I suspect what you are actually looking for is a mechanism to implement and reference a unique, incrementing primary key.  Syntax aside, and API aside (there are issues with both of them) I think some research into the MySQL [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) and [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) concepts will be quite useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-query.php) returns a MySQL resource. To display the contents of the resource, you can fetch the the result and display it like this:

```
// For the first query:
$row = mysql_fetch_row( $newid );
echo $row[0]; // To display the first column of the result set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides you're using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, the query result of `mysql_query()` function is not a number, string, array etc. You must fetch this query result for example using [`mysql_fetch_row()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) function.

Instead this deprecated library consider using mysqli extension or the PDO.